# AWS DynamoDB Scan For Value in Array

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am relatively new to AWS and DynamoDB. I have created a table with an array property. Is it possible for me to scan the array and return objects that contain a certain string?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. But keep in mind that a *scan* is an expensive operation which consumes a lot more read capacity units than a *query* operation. It would be better if you create a primary key on the column and do a query. You can find some examples here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryScanORMModelExample.html

Comment: So I can query an array value? Lets say my Table named Photos has a list property users. Can I query all Objects that contain a certain user's id within the list?

Comment: @csweeney285 - You could use a filter but it won't be efficient. How many users does a "photo" usually have?